# What is the right way to enable deferRendering in Jquery DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am looking at improving the performance of JQuery DataTable. I read about [deferRendering](http://www.datatables.net/examples/ajax/defer_render.html)  option. What i understand is when this option is enabled, once `TR` and `TD` are drawn, they are retained and need not be drawn again. Please correct my understanding.

some of the examples I have seen they are using `deferRender` property and some are using `bDeferRender` property. Which option is correct?

I am showing around 300 records at a time in grid & loading data from server. How can I check if deferRender option is improving performance

Comment: Compare speeds on FireBug

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the version of DataTables you are using.

[Converting parameter names for 1.10](http://www.datatables.net/upgrade/1.10-convert) You could find the two names here.

For checking if it works, simply output something in "createdRow" callback function, so you can count the actual number of created rows.